# How to trigger a fetch to pick next page on clicking next button react

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am building an application to display data from a django rest api. The data in django rest api is paginated using pagination_class. So I am trying to make the frontend pagination to be completely dependent on the backend.

Currently the data gets fetched and loads for first page in api(`http://localhost:8000/cluster/37/tasks`), in my pagination, I want to attempt two trials :

1. I want when I click on next in the pagination, it should trigger the fetch to load the next page from the api. In this case it would be the second page, so it should fetch from (`http://localhost:8000/cluster/37/tasks?page=2`)
2. I have a list of page numbers on the pagination, so when I click on page number four, it should trigger a fetch from page 4 of the api (`http://localhost:8000/cluster/37/tasks?page=4`)

How could I achieve that. Below is some important part of my code with some more details in it :

```
class TasksApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      columnDefs: [
        { headerName: 'Status', field: 'status' },
        { headerName: 'Started', field: 'rut_creation_time' },
        {
          headerName: 'Duration', field: 'duration'
        },
        { headerName: 'Run', field: 'run_id' },
        { headerName: 'Total Requests', valueGetter: '' },
        {
          headerName: 'Download',
          cellRenderer: 'btnCellRenderer',
          cellRendererParams: {
            clicked: function (params) {
              console.log(params)
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      defaultColDef: { resizable: true },
      frameworkComponents: {
        btnCellRenderer: BtnCellRenderer,
      },
      rowData: null,
      rowModelType: 'serverSide',
      cacheBlockSize: 10,
      dataLength: 0,
      id: this.props.location.state.id,
      headerHeight: 39,
      rowHeight: 49,
      paginationPageSize: 10,
      totalPages: null,
      currentPage: null,
      pageSize: null,
      pageNumberList: [],
      pageSizeList: [],
      startIndex: 0,
      endIndex: 5,
    };
  }

  onGridReady = params => {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    const updateData = data => {
      this.setState({ 
        rowData: data['results'],//returns the data of the page 
        dataLength: data['totalDataOnPage'], //returns the length of data in page
        totalData: data['totalData'],//returns length of total data
        currentPage: data['currentPage'],//returns the current page number
        totalPages:data['totalPages'],//returns the total pages
        nextLink: data['nextPage'],//contains the next link
        previousLink : data['previousPage']//contains the previous link
      })
      var Server = createServer(this.state.rowData);
      var datasource = createServerSideDatasource(Server);
      params.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
    };

    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/cluster/${this.state.id}/tasks`, options)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => updateData(data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  };

  onBtNext = () => {
    //how do I attempt this to lead to the next page (fetch from http://localhost:8000/cluster/37/tasks?page=<next-page>)
  };

  gotoPage = () => {
    //how do I attempt this to lead to a specific page. for example if I click on page 4, it should trigger fetch from `http://localhost:8000/cluster/37/tasks?page=4`
 }

  render() {
      console.log('data', this.state.rowData)
      console.log('pages', this.state.totalPages)
      console.log('next', this.state.nextLink)
      console.log('previous', this.state.previousLink)
    return (
      <>
        <Wrapper>
          <InnerWrapper>
            <TableContent>
              <Fragment>
                <FullScreenDataGrid style={{ flexDirection: 'column', flex: '1 1 0%' }}>
                  <div className="ag-matrix" style={{ position: 'absolute', left: '0px', top: '0px', right: '0px', bottom: '0px' }}>
                    <AgGridReact
                      columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                      rowModelType={this.state.rowModelType}
                      cacheBlockSize={this.state.cacheBlockSize}
                      debug={true}
                      defaultColDef={this.state.defaultColDef}
                      headerHeight={this.state.headerHeight}
                      rowHeight={this.state.rowHeight}
                      overlayNoRowsTemplate={this.state.overlayNoRowsTemplate}
                      pagination={true}
                      // onRowClicked={this.rowClicked}
                      frameworkComponents={this.state.frameworkComponents}
                      // paginationPageSize={this.state.paginationPageSize}
                      onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
                      suppressPaginationPanel={true}
                      onPaginationChanged={this.onPaginationChanged.bind(this)}
                    />
                  </div>
                </FullScreenDataGrid>
                <div className="Pagination-View MatrixGridFooter_DataGridFooter_3NolQ" style={{ height: '64px', marginTop: '2px' }}>
                  <PaginationSectorTwo>
//previous button comes here
                      <PageDirection onClick={() => this.onBtPrevious()}>
                        <ChevronLeft style={{ padding: '5px' }} />
                      </PageDirection>
//list of page numbers
                    <PageList>
                      {
                        this.state.pageNumberList.slice(this.state.startIndex, this.state.endIndex).map(PageNumber => (
                          <Page onClick={this.gotoPage} key={PageNumber} value={PageNumber} className={PageNumber === this.state.currentPage ? 'linkactive' : ''}>
                            {PageNumber}
                          </Page>
                        ))}
                    </PageList>
//next button comes here.
                      <PageDirection onClick={() => this.onBtNext()} style={{marginLeft: '15px'}}>
                        <ChevronRight style={{ padding: '5px' }} />
                      </PageDirection> 
                  </PaginationSectorTwo>
                </div>
              </Fragment>
            </TableContent>
          </InnerWrapper>
        </Wrapper>
      </>

    )
  }

}
```

Besides I am using `ag-grid` to display my data from a `django rest framework` api
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier with functional component using Hooks. However, with class component you can approach this by calling the callback function of `this.setState({}, () => {//callback})`

Here's a quick [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-gareth-hm5xo?file=/src/App.js) example that might help you.